# Problemas ao tentar criar um serviço na aws utilizando serverless

Tags: amazon-aws

Estou tentando criar um serviço na AWS utilizando serverless mas ao tentar dar executar o comando sls deploy, é me apresentado o seguinte erro:
An error occurred: IamRoleLambdaExecution - Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 79ded390-d2b7-4987-86a4-facaad77b2f7; Proxy: null).

este é meu arquivo serverless.yml

```
service: analysis

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - rekognition: DetectLabels
      Resource: "*"

functions:
  analysis:
    handler: handler.main

    events:
      - http:
          path: analyse
          method: get
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que a policy esta no formato incorreto, tente da seguinte maneira:

```
service: analysis

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - 'rekognition:DetectLabels'
      Resource: "*"

functions:
  analysis:
    handler: handler.main

    events:
      - http:
          path: analyse
          method: get
```